# Creating a Xamarin Binding project for PebbleKit iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

For the past while I've been trying to create a binding project in Xamarin for PebbleKit iOS (the SDK for the Pebble smart watches). My hope is that in doing this I can create a Xamarin C# app that communicates with a Pebble smart watch, just like how you would in Objective - C.

Here is a link to the github page containing the code: https://github.com/dankunc/PebbleKit-Xamarin/tree/master

Also, here is a link to a simple harness project that just contains a button you can use to test out the binding project: https://github.com/dankunc/PebbleKit-Xamarin-Harness

Note: If any of you are kind enough to download the code and try it out, you'll probably need to update the reference path in the harness to the .dll in the binding project (PebbleKitAll/bin/release/PebbleKitAll.dll)

The project compiles, however when I go to use it in an actual Xamarin app, this code returns null to watch:

```
var watch = PBCentral.DefaultCentral();
```

In objective - c, the equivalent method would never return null, and I've been struggling with this for quite some time.

The PebbleKit binding project relies on two .frameworks from Pebble (PebbleKit and PebbleVendor) and a handful of other frameworks that get included in the harness project. I generated the ApiDefinition and StructsAndEnums files from using Objective Sharpie which I then cleaned up afterwards.

If anyone is able to help me with this, or if I need to provide more information or anything else, please let me know, and anything is appreciated. I've been struggling with this for quite a while and am at wits end. Thank you.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I really need to get this running.
Maybe you can also answer to my question?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072363/xamarin-obj-c-framework-binding?noredirect=1#comment52041295_32072363