# Xamarin Obj-C Framework Binding (PebbleKit iOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I try to Bind [this](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-ios-sdk/) (PebbleKit.Framework) Framework to C# with Objecttive Sharpie on the command line.

```
sharpie bind -o Binding -f PebbleKit.Framework -sdk iphoneos8.4
```

This is working without errors, but how do I get it to bind all Header Files?
I just get 3 partial interfaces with name constants (with Verify Attribute).
And some NSNumber from PBWatch+Sports.h for Example

```
extern NSNumber *PBSportsTimeKey;
```

Do I have to bind methods and classes manually?

Comment: Why don't you use this: https://github.com/dankunc/PebbleKit-Xamarin/tree/master ?

Comment: Because it is not working... I really need this SDK in Xamarin. So I have to try everything.